# Using Firebase as an Authenticating Middleware in Express.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I am currently in the process of creating an auth middleware to ensure there is a valid firebase token in the request header. The code is as follows:

**auth.ts**

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase-admin';
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';

const getAuthToken = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  if (req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[0] === 'Bearer') {
    req.authToken = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
  } else {
    req.authToken = null;
  }
  next();
};

export const checkIfAuthenticated = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  getAuthToken(req, res, async () => {
    try {
      const { authToken } = req;
      const userInfo = await firebase.auth().verifyIdToken(authToken);
      req.authId = userInfo.uid;
      return next();
    } catch (e) {
      return res.status(401).send({ error: 'You are not authorized to make this request' });
    }
  });
};

export const checkIfAdmin = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  getAuthToken(req, res, async () => {
    try {
      const authToken = req;
      const userInfo = await firebase.auth().verifyIdToken(authToken);
      if (userInfo.admin === true) {
        req.authId = userInfo.uid;
        return next();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return res.status(401).send({ error: 'You are not authorized to make this request' });
    }
  });
};
```

**app.ts**

```
app.get('/api/users', checkIfAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  executeQuery('SELECT * from user')
    .then(function (results: unknown) {
      res.send(results);
    })
    .catch(function (err: unknown) {
      res.status(400).send(err);
    });
});
```

However, in auth.ts I keep getting the following errors, how do I fix them:

**1. In getAuthToken**

> Error:(6, 9) TS2339: Property 'authToken' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>'.

> Error:(8, 9) TS2339: Property 'authToken' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>'.

**2. In checkIfAuthenticated**

> Error:(16, 15) TS2339: Property 'authToken' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>'.

> Error:(18, 11) TS2339: Property 'authId' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>'.

**3. In checkIfAdmin**

> Error:(30, 60) TS2345: Argument of type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

> Error:(32, 13) TS2339: Property 'authId' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed it as follows:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase-admin';
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';

export interface IGetAuthTokenRequest extends Request {
  authToken: string;
  authId: string;
}

const getAuthToken = (req: IGetAuthTokenRequest, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  if (req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[0] === 'Bearer') {
    req.authToken = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
  } else {
    req.authToken = null;
  }
  next();
};

export const checkIfAuthenticated = (
  req: IGetAuthTokenRequest,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) => {
  getAuthToken(req, res, async () => {
    try {
      const { authToken } = req;
      const userInfo = await firebase.auth().verifyIdToken(authToken);
      req.authId = userInfo.uid;
      return next();
    } catch (e) {
      return res.status(401).send({ error: 'You are not authorized to make this request' });
    }
  });
};

export const checkIfAdmin = (req: IGetAuthTokenRequest, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  getAuthToken(req, res, async () => {
    try {
      const userInfo = await firebase.auth().verifyIdToken(req.authToken);
      if (userInfo.admin === true) {
        req.authId = userInfo.uid;
        return next();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return res.status(401).send({ error: 'You are not authorized to make this request' });
    }
  });
```

Comment: Works like a charm when applying on specific routes. Did you succeed to use it on the express instance directly through app.use(middleware)? It is not working on my side.

Comment: Not at all, I didn't get that far. Glad to see it helped!

Answer (score 1):

I was getting some error with the accepted answer, so i wrote a quick fix based on previous answer:

```js
import * as firebase from "firebase-admin";
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";

declare global {
  namespace Express {
    export interface Request {
      authToken?: string;
      authId?: string;
    }
  }
}

const getAuthToken = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  if (
    req.headers.authorization &&
    req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[0] === "Bearer"
  ) {
    req.authToken = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
  } else {
    req.authToken = "";
  }
  next();
};

export const checkIfAuthenticated = (
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) => {
  getAuthToken(req, res, async () => {
    try {
      const { authToken } = req;
      if (!authToken) throw new Error("Unauthenticated!");

      const userInfo = await firebase.auth().verifyIdToken(authToken);
      req.authId = userInfo.uid;
      return next();
    } catch (e) {
      return res
        .status(401)
        .send({ error: "You are not authorized to make this request" });
    }
  });
};

export const checkIfAdmin = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    getAuthToken(req, res, async () => {
      try {
        if (!req.authToken) throw new Error("Unauthenticated!");
        const userInfo = await firebase.auth().verifyIdToken(req.authToken);
        if (userInfo.admin === true) {
          req.authId = userInfo.uid;
          return next();
        }
      } catch (e) {
        return res.status(401).send({ error: 'You are not authorized to make this request' });
      }
    });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).