# How to implement Angular Social Login with Express Server

Tags: angular, express

I have successfully implemented Angular Social Login into my Angular app, but now I need to implement it into the server part of the application, which I have done in Node.js with Express. What am I suppose to do? I understand it is something to do with the token that Google sends, but what exactly is the way to implement this token with Express? Can you please point me to some source for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options to achieve this
I'm assuming you're going to use JSON Web Tokens of some sort. If so, then you'd get your token from the FrontEnd, you then would attach the token to the header of your requests and the Backend would authenticate the validity of the token

Some good options would be to use a service like Auth0 ([here's a quickstart guide](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/express)) or Firebase ([Add Firebase to your JavaScript project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup))

Some Links that may help:

- [Add the Firebase Admin SDK to your server(firebase docs)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup)
- [Authenticate a Firebase User on the Server(fireship.io)](https://fireship.io/snippets/express-middleware-auth-token-firebase/)
- [Using Firebase as an Authenticating Middleware in Express.js(stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64205096/using-firebase-as-an-authenticating-middleware-in-express-js)